# Allocating memory for structure (stack)

Tags: c

so i am trying to implement some form of stack. Here is definition i have in my header file:

```
struct tStack
{
    int data;
    struct tStack *dptr;
};
```

Then i have a function to inicialize the stack in other file that from what it is called:

```
int stack_init(struct tStack *top)
{
    top = (struct tStack*)malloc(sizeof(struct tStack));
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return E_INTERN;
    }
    top->data = '#';
    top->dptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

And i call the init function in my main file like this:

```
struct tStack *top = NULL;
int err = 0;

err = stack_init(top);
```

The problem is that the stack will not get inicialized and the pointer to top is still null.
I think the problem is somewhere in passing pointers, because i am not good with pointers :D

Comment: you're passing in a `struct tStack *` to `stack_init`. this means the allocation you do is only assigned to a shadow parameter, and has no effect from the outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack_init function makes a copy of the pointer - local to the stack_init function, which ceases to exist as soon as stack_init finishes. Top will actually not be null in the body of your stack_init function.

You can do this:

```
struct tStack {
    int data;
    struct tStack *dptr;
};

int stack_init(struct tStack **top) {
    *top = (struct tStack*)malloc(sizeof(struct tStack));
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return ERR;
    }
    (*top)->data = '#';
    (*top)->dptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct tStack *top = NULL;
    int err = 0;
    err = stack_init(&top);
}
```